# GLPK/glpsol options

Tags: optimization, solver, glpk

Following glpk documentation, I'm able to pass options to glpk stand-alone solver (glpsol), those options are described in Appendix D, ex: `--tmlim 60`.`

However, looking at *2.10 Mixed integer programming routine*, I see that there are much more options handled by glpk, ex: `tol_int` or `out_frq`.

Some options seem to be unavailable with glpsol since they are not listed in Appendix D...

My question: Are they really unavailable, if no, how do I pass them (ex: `tol_int`) to glpsol?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*glpsol* supports only a subset of the parameters that are available in the GLPK library. These are all listed by *glpsol --help*.

If you need access to any other parameter you have to write program that calls the GlPK library.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:
`prob1.solve(GLPK_CMD(options=["--tmlim", "900"]))`